nestjs Header decorator conflicting with js native header
I am new to nestjs and I was trying to use the @Headers() decorator to get access to the headers of the request. here is the code:
import { Body, Controller, Post } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  @Post()
  public createUser(@Body('email') email: string, @Headers() reqHeaders: any) {
    return 'You sent a request to create a user';
  }
}

but I am getting the below error from typescript:
Value of type '{ new (init?: HeadersInit): Headers; prototype: Headers; }' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?ts(2348)

It seems that typescript is confusing js native headers with the Headers decorator of nestjs. Or maybe the problem is something else?
I would appreciate any help with fixing this typescript error.
thanks.

Just import Headers from @nestjs-common:
import { Body, Controller, Post, Headers } from '@nestjs/common';


what a nooby mistake i have here. thanks.
